# How do you perform haptic feedback IMMEDIATELY after a button is touched

Tags: android, button

Note: I do NOT want the haptic feedback to happen after the click is released, but when the button is touched. Here is my code so far. As of right now it will vibrate and switch activities after the touch is released. I want it to vibrate when the user touches it and switch activities after the touch is released.

```
back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        v.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.VIRTUAL_KEY);
        decideGeneration();
    }
});
```

Comment: Use `setOnTouchListener()` instead of `setOnClickListener()`, then.

Comment: Your call back is specifically and explicitly tied to a full "click".

Answer (score 0):

Use `setOnTouchListener()` and check the event if it's `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`

Comment: yes, there is a built-in delay on 'click' of 300 MS. Touch has no delay.